# Stored procedure: Searching in a table when passing an array of values

Tags: sql-server, arrays, stored-procedures, parameters

I need to create a stored procedure which receives a parameter (named @codes).

This is a string which contains a list of codes separated by a semicolumn.
I'd need to look inside a table and return all rows that have a code (which is in the column EANcodes) which was passed in the @codes parameter.

Can anyone help me get started. My knowledge of stored procedures is very limited.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, I'd prefer to see the parameter passed in another way, either using a [table-value parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx) (assuming SQL 2008) or XML which can be easily shredded into a table.

Alternatively, use a SQL split function (one example is [here](http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/20009)) to parse the string into a temp table, then join against that table in your select query.

Answer (score 0):

Stored Procedures aren't really meant to handle a list of strings as a paramter. You'd be better off splitting it up in your App code and then calling the stored procedure many times with each one as a parameter.

However, if you feel the need to do it this way. You could loop through the string, and use CHARINDEX to find the next index of a semicolon and then use SUBSTRING to get the next code. Then you could use a CTE for the matching rows at each iteration and when the loop is done, simply return the CTE. This is pretty hacky, but I can't think of any other way to do this.
(Those are the T-SQL string functions)

For info on the string manipulation functions (in T-SQL): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx

And here are similar functions in MySQL: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html

Comment: Or, for a quick and dirty solution, use REPLACE() to turn the semicolons into commas, then use dynamic SQL to shove that into an IN (...) clause. But I couldn't really recommend that as an answer, because doing that kind of thing is a big indication that you've got your design wrong!